# How to create scale-free networks with different assortativity in NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Given that [assortativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity) is the preference of the hubs of a network to connect to other hubs instead of peripheral nodes, I want to produce 2 scale-free networks using the Barabasi-Albert algorithm with different assortativity.

One visual example of this is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity#/media/File:Scale-free_networks_for_different_degrees_of_assortativity.jpg).

**How can I "force" NetworkX to create a few scale-free networks with assortativity coefficients that are significantly different from each other, like the ones in the visual example?**

This is how I create the (undirected) Barabasi-Albert network:

```
import networkx as nx
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%pylab inline

n=100 #Number of nodes
ncols=10 #Number of columns in a 10x10 grid of positions

m=2  #Number of initial links
seed=[100]

for j in seed: 
    G=nx.barabasi_albert_graph(n, m, j)
    pos = {i : (i // ncols, (n-i-1) % ncols) for i in G.nodes()}
    d=G.degree().values()
    avg_d=round(sum(d)/100,3)
    avg_degree.append(avg_d)
    edges.append(len(G.edges()))
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True, nodesize=100, node_color='darkorange',font_size=10)  
    plt.title('Scale-Free Network (BA)')
    plt.show()

#Assortativity coefficient (Pearson's rho)
r=nx.degree_pearson_correlation_coefficient(G)
```

This network has an assortativity coefficient of `-0.2`, which means that hubs have a slight preference to attach to peripheral nodes.

Comment: The Barabasi-Albert algorithm is a specific algorithm.  The parameters in the BA algorithm do not allow you to tune the assortativity.  If you want to tune the assortativity, you'll need to use a modification of the algorithm, or use a different algorithm to generate the network.